# Got error while installing Jomsocial Ajax System in Jooma 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, jomsocial

I tried to install a Jomsocial 2.6.0 for my Joomla site (2.5.6) and I got en error while installing Ajax System, it could not copy a specific file, I made all the needed files for the installation writable but it did not work eather:

Copy failed
JInstaller: :Install: Failed to copy file ...../home/components/com_community/install_5132235717102/azrul.system.php to ...../home/plugins/system/azrul.system/azrul.system.php

Installing Jomsocial Ajax System
Extraction..... 
Failed
3-3c COM_INSTALLER_INSTALL_ERROR : Ajax system installation failed.

Thanks in advance
Mouad

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I had to change the files permessions to 755